Applying Thevenin theorem on pure resistive ac circuit

This review problem has been stumping me for days (very rusty). My initial approach was hooking up what I believe would be an AC source with \$V_p \times \cos(1000 \times 2\pi)\$ in series with an Rth and the changeable load resistances as the load.
Finding the Vp or Ip value has been the biggest roadblock for me. I thought I could find Ip by simply doing \$(V_\text{pp}/2)/(R_L)\$ for a random table selection, but this doesn't make sense since the amplitude is supposed to be constant. Only progress I've made was realize that the power factor is 1 and the circuit is in phase because of the pure resistive trait. Any tips or pointers as to how to approach this problem? Been having a tough time searching up similar uses of the thevenin theorem.

I like it. This is a great exercise!

@Theattack55 can you provide a source for the image?

TheAttack, What do you know about the maximum power theorem?

@pipe IKR? First time I can see a reward through a problem, but it's a tough one for me.

@periblepsis That actually came up as I searched up similar approaches. Now that I think about it I was treading a similar path earlier until I got stuck. I used the average power formula (Vm x Im x Cos(0) x 1/2). I set Vm equal to a random constant 3 then came up with two separate equations that had separate values of Im which I substituted with Im = (Vpp/2)/(RL+Rth) where Vpp and RL were the table values. I equated them and thought I found the answer for Rth, but it only worked for 2 out of the 7 table values.

Seems like you have a voltage divider with one unknown resistance, driven by a voltage source with an unknown value.  But you have multiple data points for one resistance and the divider voltage.  You only need two equations in two unknowns to find the answers.

@JohnD I did try this, and it worked fine for those 2 table values. I took the first table value as (2.56/2) = Vm[33/(33+Rth)] and the last one I worked by equating Vm = (0.78/2)/[5/(5+Rth)]. Solved to obtain what I thought would be the Rth value. It's when I analyzed the current of the other table values that I noticed this value wasn't true for the rest.

@TheAttack55 I tried it and all the table values were consistent with my answers.  So maybe try again?

@JohnD I don’t understand how you got an answer that perfectly crosses all data points.  From what I see in the table, the slopes between each data point is slightly different which means the system is non-linear. A decent approximation would be to do what TheAttack55 did and pick the first and last points to create a line from which would get close to most of the points. Is that what you did?

@TheAttack55 My answer here is related to what’s going on im this question and gives the generic formulas. This is a very useful technique and am very glad it’s actually being taught in school. Many of my colleagues don’t know this at all. I actually just taught a class on this exact topic at my local hackerspace/makerspace last month to try and spread the word.

@SteKulov My answer didn't give EXACT results, but  0.78, 1.126, 1.41, 1.786, 2.127, 2.347, and 2.56.  Well within what you might expect from experimental error.  You wouldn't expect the points to lie on a line since a voltage divider is R2/(R1+R2).

@JohnD  Oh, OK.  I thought that was what TheAttack55 was trying to say, but on second look it sounds like they might have just made a mistake in the calculation???  I get the same values as you if I use the first and last data points (Vth=4.32 and Rth=22.7).  By line, I mean the I-V curve.  The I-V curve of this unknown circuit when you consider all the data points is slightly non-linear.  So the Thevenin equivalent can only be an approximation to "best-fit" the points, as pointed out in qrk's answer.  https://i.sstatic.net/9Qgn8UaK.png https://i.sstatic.net/pz0M6Yfg.png

Draw the circuit diagram.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
This is one way of solving the problem for two unknowns (VT & RT):
Write the equation for Vo.
Rearrange the equation to solve for RT. This will give a function in the form of RT(Vo,RL) = some_equation
Since RT should be the same, choose two lines in the table and solve for VT.
With VT known (around 4.4 V), you can figure out RT (around 24 ohms). The numbers in the table don't give a clean answer (as in VT and RT are the exact same numbers) which may be part of the question to come up with an average value.
Where the power peaks up in the load (as suggested by @periblepsis) is another way of finding RT which in this case lies somewhere between 22 & 27 ohms.

Hmmm…some kind of averaging is what I initially thought of too. Then I thought it might be possible that whoever wrote this review problem might want an equivalent circuit for each adjacent pair of points.  You think that’s possible too or a little too crazy?

@SteKulov Anything is possible since we don't know what the chapter is about. Perhaps an exercise in a real world problem where errors in measurements can create a conundrum.
